# Angular 12 - Using class as http observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-observable

Using **Angular 12**

The HTTP service returns the following response from the backend

```js
Array<{
   id: string;
   title: string;
   created: string;
}>

// Service
public list(): Observable<Array<Item>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<Item>>(url);
}

// Component
this.service.list().subscribe(res => {
  this.item = res;
});
```

Created a model class to typecast the response

```js
export class Item {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  created: string;

  get parsedTitle() {
    const t = this.title;
    // do some parsing on title
    return t;
  }
}
```

In the HTML, want to use `parsedTitle` to print the parsed title, but it prints nothing.

Tried changing getter to function `public parsedTitle(){}` then it gives error, `parsedTitle is not a function`.

**How can I typecast the returned observable as class instances from array of objects?**

Comment: You can't "typecast" them - TypeScript **does not** exist at runtime, you need to instantiate the class using the (vanilla object) data from JSON. Use interfaces to represent the JSON, it _only_ has data (no behaviour). Collection of possible dupes: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the plain objects to the real `Item` class. Try something like this:

```js
// class
class Item {
    constructor(item: Partial<Item>) {
        Object.assign(this, item);
    }

    id: string = '';
    title: string = '';
    created: string = '';

    get parsedTitle() {
        const t = this.title;
        // do some parsing on title
        return t;
    }
}

// Service
public list(): Observable<Array<Item>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<Item>>(url).pipe(
    map(items => items.map(item => new Item(item))),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you should use classes in other programming languages. Usually you need to instantiate an object of that type using the class constructor in order to have something to call your methods on (unless the methods are static of course).

Extrapolating that to your use case, you should not just try to *tell* typescript to treat the objects that you just got from the API as if they were instances of `Item`, but build `Item` instances with them.

Add a constructor to your item class that receives a parameter and copies all the properties it finds in that object into `this` (the current instance).

```
export class Item {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  created: string;

  constructor(item?: Item) {
    Object.assign(this, item ?? {});
  }

  get parsedTitle() {
    const t = this.title;
    // do some parsing on title
    return t;
  }
}
```

And in your service class, make sure to transform the objects you get from the API into an actual array of instances of type `Item` like so:

```
// Service
public list(): Observable<Array<Item>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<Item>>(url).pipe(
    map(item => new Item(item))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the object that comes from the backend (`JSON`) is serialized to the target type (`Item` in your case) without initializing it using its constructor.

So if you need to achieve what you're trying to do, you have to initialize every `object` using the `Item` contractor by `new Item()`.

So you can try something like the following:

**item.model.ts:**

```js
export class Item {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  created: string;

  get parsedTitle() {
    const t = this.title;
    // do some parsing on title
    return t;
  }

  constructor(item: Partial<Item>) {
    Object.assign(this, item);
  }
}
```

**items.service.ts:**

```js
// Service
public list(): Observable<Array<Item>> {
  return this.http
    .get<Array<Item>>(url)
    .pipe(map(items => items.map(item => new Item(item))));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, you are not instantiating Item class and putting API response to it. Once API returns response, the conversion from response to Item class won't happen automatically. You only need to handle conversion.
As per your code, code tries to access `title` over this where `this` will never be available since you haven't instantiated it.

Try below code (minor change):

// Service

```
public list(): Observable<Array<Item>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<Item>>(url)
         .pipe(map((items) => (items.map((item) => (new Item(item))))));
}
```